# Generating synthetic data with Gaussian distribution

Tags: python

## Problem

In a [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.04561.pdf) I am reading now, it defines a new metric and authors claim some advantages over previous metrics. They verify their claim by some synthetic data, which looks like following

[image]

The implementation of their metric is pretty straightforward. However, I am not sure how they create this kind of synthetic data.

## What I Have Done

This looks like Gaussian where `x` is only within certain intervals, I tried with following code but did not get anything similar to the plot presented in the paper.

```py
import numpy as np

def generate_gaussian(size=1000, lb=-0.1, up=0.1):
    data = np.random.randn(5000)
    data = data[(data <= up) & (data >= lb)][:size]
    return data

np.random.seed(1234)
base = generate_gaussian()
background_pos = base + 0.3
background_neg = base + 0.7
```

[image]

Now I am wondering if the authors create these data using some special distribution (other than Gaussian) I do not know?

Comment: Could you use the [`numpy.random.normal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html) function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have cut off the data at +/- 0.1. A normalised Gausian distribution only 'looks Gaussian' if you look over the range approximately +/- 3. Try this:

```
import numpy as np

def generate_gaussian(size=1000, lb=-3, up=3):
    data = np.random.randn(5000)
    data = data[(data <= up) & (data >= lb)][:size]
    return data

np.random.seed(1234)
base = generate_gaussian()
background_pos = base + 5
background_neg = base + 15
```

Comment: I guess this is $\bm 3$ is related to $\bm 3\sigma$, which is my case $\sigma=1$. I should have thought of this. Thank you for your clarification!

Answer (score 2):

Numpy has a [`numpy.random.normal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html) that draws random samples from a normal (Gaussian) distribution.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


sigma = 0.05
s0 = np.random.normal(0.2, sigma, 5000)
s1 = np.random.normal(0.6, sigma, 5000)

plt.hist(s0, 300, density=True, color="b")
plt.hist(s1, 300, density=True, color="r")
plt.xlim(0, 1)
plt.show()
```

[image: Histograms]

You can change the values of the `mu` (mean) and `sigma` to alter the distributions

```py
mu = 0.55
sigma = 0.1
dist = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 5000)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scipy.stats.norm` ([info](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html)).

import libraries

```
>>> from scipy.stats import norm
>>> from matplotlib import pyplot
```

plot

```
>>> pyplot.hist(norm.rvs(loc=1, scale=0.5, size=10000), bins=30, alpha=0.5, label='norm_1')
>>> pyplot.hist(norm.rvs(loc=5, scale=0.5, size=10000), bins=30, alpha=0.5, label='norm_2')
>>> pyplot.legend()
>>> pyplot.show()
```

[image]

---

Clarification:

A normal distribution is defined by mean (`loc`, distribution center) and standard distribution (`scale`, measure of distribution dispersion or width). `rvs` generates random samples of the desired normal distribution of size `size`. For example next code generates 4 random elements of a normal distribution (mean = 1, SD = 1).

```
>>> norm.rvs(loc=1, scale=1, size=4)
array([ 0.52154255,  1.40873701,  1.55959291, -0.01730568])
```

Comment: I think `np.random.randn` indeed generates standard normal distribution (see [doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.randn.html)). But obviously it does not support numerous statistics as in `scipy.stats.norm`.